# Can I translate a range of data in Google Sheet with GoogleTranslate foruma?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-translate

I am using the Google foruma GOOGLETRANSLATE
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en

It can translate a single cell.
How to use this formula to translate a range cells?
Tried arrayforuma, it is not taking any effect.

Thanks for sharing your Google sheets knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

inspired by NataliaGo
i made compact version, no need arrayformula, input your proper options
=TransPose(Split(GoogleTranslate(Join(". ",A1:A), "en", "ko"),". ",false,false))

exception is "ja", they change even if it is delimiter
=TransPose(Split(GoogleTranslate(Join(". ",A1:A), "en", "ja"),"。 ",true))

Answer (score 1):

with new functions it is now doable:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A100; LAMBDA(x; GOOGLETRANSLATE(x; "en"; "de"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ARRAYFORMULA` does not support `GOOGLETRANSLATE`. The best you can have is to pre-program the array like this:

```
={GOOGLETRANSLATE(B20, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B21, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B22, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B23, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B24, "en", "de")}
```

[image]

Another workaround would be to join stuff:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 GOOGLETRANSLATE(TEXTJOIN(". ", 1, B20:B24), "en", "de"), "."))))
```

[image]

You may also resolve it via script or with API calls: **https://developers.google.com/apps-script**

---

to batch it out use:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA("={"&TEXTJOIN(";"&CHAR(10), 1, "GOOGLETRANSLATE(B"&
 ROW(B20:B1300)&", ""en"", ""de"")")&"}")}
```

and then copy-paste formula where you need it

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.

My column has about 1300 rows.  How to pre-configure B20 to B24 etc (in my case B1300) in batch?

Comment: I also tried the second option.  My columns have html inside. It is breaking the html and putting them into several rows.